# Hotswapping server runtime behavior dynamically from client

Tags: java, dynamic, client-server, hotswap

Say I've got a logging service deployed to some (jaxrs-compliant) container.

```
@Path("/logger")
public class LogService
{
  @GET
  @Path("/log")
  public Response log(final String @QueryParam("msg") msg)
  {
     System.out.println(msg);
     // ...
  }
}
```

If I make the following request to the container hosting this service, I expect to see the output of my message to the container's stdout log:

```
GET <host>:<port>/logger/log?msg=foo
```

Now I'd like to change the implementation of this log message at runtime with behavior specified by some arbitrary client.

For example, say we had an interface:

```
public interface LoggerApi
{
  void logMessage(final String msg);
}
```

and the service was redefined to use an implementation of this interface:

```
@Path("/logger")
public class LogService
{
  public static LoggerApi LOGGER = new LoggerApi()
    {
      void logMessage(final String msg)
      {
        System.out.println(msg);
      }
    }

  @GET
  @Path("/log")
  public Response log(final String @QueryParam("msg") msg)
  {
    LOGGER.logMessage(msg);
    // ...
  }
}
```

The question thus becomes, how can I hot swap the implementation of logger with a new implementation defined by some client external to the server.

My first instinct was that RMI and/or dynamic proxies could get me where I wanted to be, but I'm not soo sure with all the security policy madness.

Essentially what I want is the ability to do the following:

```
@Path("/config")
public class ConfigService
{
  @POST
  @Path("/loggerApi")
  public Response setLoggerApi(final LoggerApi clientSuppliedLogger)
  {
    LogService.LOGGER = clientSuppliedLogger;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Thoughts?

(Oh and I know this poses a severe security risk and such a pattern ought never be used in production environments. My interest is in designing a mock service where the service's behavior and side effects can be defined by the integration tests calling the mock service)